# count from Unlimited Multiply sheets and put the total count in master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, count

> > I have a code but I don't know why it's not showing the total count of all sheets in the sheet(summary) it has to show the total count of all sheets in any column of the sheet (summary) And all the count have to be separate like sheet1 in "A1", Sheet2 in "A2" and go on to all other sheets like that. I'd have attached the image also what I'm doing Just one more thing I want to do is work on the Unlimited worksheet skipping the worksheet(summary) and don't count 0 zero.

```
Sub SheetsSum()
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim X               As Double
Dim arrTotalSum()   As Variant

With ThisWorkbook
 
    
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "cover" Then
          
             X = X + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrTotalSum(1 To .Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)
            arrTotalSum(X, 1) = "Quantity  " & ws.name
            arrTotalSum(X, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D4:E6"), ">0")
           
        End If
    Next ws
 
    .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(X, 2).Value = arrTotalSum
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If the issues is `countif` please suggest any other way to do it

Comment: Your Formula is always referring to the ActiveSheet.  Use `ws.Range("D4:E6")`

Comment: Yes I'm newcomer and learning vba

Comment: Just put my data as simple as can to learn

Comment: If there is any way better then this please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my other answer it's best to have the ReDim outside the loop if possible. A preserve is an "expensive" operation and unless it is really neccessary to do a ReDim Preserve avoid it

```
Sub SheetsSum()
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim X               As Double
    Dim arrTotalSum()   As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook
 
        ' A preserve is an "expensive" operation
        ' Unless it is really neccessary to do a ReDim Preserve avoid it
        ' especially in a loop
        ReDim arrTotalSum(1 To .Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)
        
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "cover" Then
          
                X = X + 1
                
                arrTotalSum(X, 1) = "Quantity  " & ws.Name
                arrTotalSum(X, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("D4:E6"), ">0")
           
            End If
        Next ws
 
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(X, 2).Value = arrTotalSum
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any teaching platform? storax

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-articles/ Start with the free articles and also have  a look on Paul's youtube channel. For a beginner there is IMHO no need to go for the paid stuff. If you master the "free" stuff there then you will know a lot more on VBA than other people. But, of course, it's up to you.

Comment: Can you please share Paul's YouTube channel link

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/c/Excelmacromastery